# How do you bind a ViewModel to the Windows 8 Settings pane in MvvmCross?

Tags: mvvm, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, mvvmcross

I've been looking at MvvmCross for cross platform mobile development.

Since navigation of views is done by calling ShowViewModel<>(), how would you create the settings pane (which is a user control) in Windows 8 using MvvmCross?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MvvmCross provides a general `ShowViewModel<T>` navigation mechanism which uses a Presenter to display and set the DataContext on `View`s. Views that are shown this way typically cover the 'whole screen' and benefit from automatically constructed ViewModels using CIRS (see http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/v3-new-viewmodel-lifecycle.html)

However, just because navigation is typically done using `ShowViewModel<T>` this doesn't prevent you from using ViewModels in other ways. Common exceptions to the `ShowViewModel<T>` mechanism are things like iOS Tabbed and SplitView children, WindowsPhone Pivot/Panorama items, Android sub-Fragments and Dialogs, and Windows8 sub-panes such as flyouts.

---

At a practical level in Windows8, every XAML UserControl has a DataContext property which you can set in code - so you can always:

- create any UserControl in code
- then create a ViewModel

  - using `new`,
  - using `Mvx.IoCConstruct<TViewModel>()`
  - or using `Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>().LoadViewModel(request, state)`
- then set the UserControls `DataContext` property
- then show the UserControl

Where you do this in your code... whether you use page code-behind, some Messenger-Message receiver or some other mechanism - well that's up to you - but this is something which is appropriate to put into the UI code project - it's definitely a View concern.

---

One final aside... while it is true that the settings pane is a `UserControl`, a `LayoutAwarePage` is also a `UserControl` too - so you can use `LayoutAwarePage` in flyouts too - but don't expect to see the `OnNavigatedTo` calls invoked when you do - e.g. see `SettingsFlyout` in http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-settings-sample-1f762f49

Comment: Thanks so much for a clear answer.  It appears the best place for documentation is your blog.  Is there a specific point in time I can start to read about v3 on your blog?  Love the N+0 series, keep it up!

Comment: Yes, you can start reading at 1:38pm today! (Other times are also allowed)

Comment: :) I meant, what date did you start blogging about the changes in v3?

Comment: @Stuart Hey Stuart! Am using Mvx.IoCConstruct<TViewModel>() to assign the data context of the user control to ViewModel. But when am referencing the UserControl in the Page, am getting an error in XAML saying "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object". And the UI in user control is not getting updated when i change the properties in View model from a different view. My view model constructor uses a service in its parameters, do i have to mention it anywhere to get the instance of the viewmodel ?

Comment: @Stuart Could you please help me with this question ? I have been stuck at it for days.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175414/how-to-bind-view-model-to-a-usercontrol-in-mvvmcross